# GWT Deselect keyboard selection

Tags: gwt, datagrid, keyboard

When keyboard selecting a row in a GWT DataGrid, how do you deselect it?
When you select a row like this:

`table.setKeyboardSelectedRow(rowInd, true);`

You can unselect the row by clicking outside the grid. How do I make this same 'unselection' programmatically?

Selecting a row like this:

`table.setKeyboardSelectedRow(rowInd, false);`

Since the focus is not on this selection, it does not blur out like usual when you click outside the grid. I need to keep the focus on something else, but I wish to still deselect this row at a certain point. How do you deselect a keyboard selection programmatically?

Note: using the Selection Model's `setSelection()` with a false param does not deselect keyboard selection, only the selection made by the selection model. Using `setKeyboardSelectedRow(-1)` also does not work.

I find it baffling that GWT does not offer a way to unselect a keyboard selected row!

Comment: What would it mean to "unselect a keyboard selected row"? "Keyboard selection" is akin to focus management, except inside of a focused grid; it's meant for navigation inside the grid. What would unselecting mean?

Comment: I wish to unselect simply to remove the highlighting (the standard yellow row highlighting that you see on GWT grids when you select a row).

When I set a keyboard selected row, the row gets highlighted, but I'm looking for a way to programmatically undo that highlighting.

The most difficult part is that the grid that I highlight is not focused (although I set a keyboard selected row, passing in false for the second param says to not steal focus). So clicking outside of the grid does not undo the highlighting because the grid was already not focused.

Comment: So I'm trying to find a way to unselect a keyboard selected row, or even just clear all keyboard selections for a grid. It does not seem like either is possible with GWT's grid keyboard selections, which I find hard to believe.